# Solar wiring question

Tags: rv

My RV is “prewired” for solar, which in my case means there are connectors on the roof.  The wires (I believe 10 gauge) end up in a compartment underneath the bed, that houses the RV’s ATS and its charger/converter. The charger/converter obviously has leads to the batteries. Getting wires out of this area is difficult. Can I hook up the solar wires to a solar controller, and then wire the output from the controller to the battery wires from the charger/converter?  What would I need in terms of extra equipment, diodes, etc.?

Comment: It's probably just a matter of adding a solar charger and connecting it directly to the battery.

Comment: Test the wires and plan for fuses and disconnects.